# What's the best way to shave off 1/8 of an inch from hardie board?

Tags: technique, backer-board

When laying hardie backer I was told to make my joints as tight as possible, so I imagine I'll run into this often.

Currently I have a standard 6' board that just barely doesn't fit inside the lip of the tub (I'm leaving a 1/4" gap below per hardie board's instructions).

### What is the best way to shave off a piece of hardy board so I can make a tight fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not saying this is the cleanest or the most practical but I will just tell you what I do...  Angle grinder with diamond blade.  I cut these pieces only outside and I wear proper goggles and mask.  It is one of the only times that I overdo safety.

This is the only way I can get a clean small cut in HB.  If I use a knife it will take a few scores, then I bend it and since the bent area is small, the break won't be even at all.

Comment: Turns out the compressor I had was underrated for my angle grinder so I used a carbide blade with my oscillating saw and it worked beautifully and left a better edge than I could score / cut.  Turns out anything over an 1/8 inch is easy to cut with a jigsaw and carbide blade.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of those cheese grater looking rasps most people use for drywall. They're called serrated contour planes.

Something like the [Stanley Surform Pocket Plane](http://www.stanleytools.com/default.asp?CATEGORY=SURFORM%20TOOLS%20AND%20BLADES&TYPE=PRODUCT&PARTNUMBER=21-399&SDesc=6"%20Surform®%20Pocket%20Plane) or [Stanley Surform Plane-Type](http://www.stanleytools.com/default.asp?CATEGORY=SURFORM+TOOLS+AND+BLADES&TYPE=PRODUCT&PARTNUMBER=21-296&SDesc=Surform%26%23174%3B+Plane+Type+%96+Regular+Cut+Blade)

Those tools will be quicker/easier and make less of a mess than using a power saw. Or at least a more controlled mess. You can also use a utility knife with a sharp blade but the rasps are easier to use and safer.

Comment: small cuts on hardieboard are hard and I don't think a rasp would do it.

Comment: @DMoore It works to shave off a little off the edge. I've done it. Also works on cement board too.

Comment: I have tried it too and my rasping isn't even over the course of 6 feet because it takes so much effort.  Maybe your rasp is better than mine.

Comment: Wow -thanks!! I'll consider this, but since I already have an angle grinder I'm going use that first.

Comment: @virtualxtc The best thing is to get the cut right the first time. Power tools make a big mess. I like to lay the panel where it's going to go (usually upside down) and mark the panel. It's faster and more accurate than using a tape measure. Then score and snap. There might be some high spots which are easy to clean up with a rasp or sharp utility knife on the opposite edge but since you marked the board upside down you'll have factory edge to factory edge in most situations.

Comment: I tried the score and snap method on the next piece, but the break didn't follow the score (I didn't have a good wide stair well to put the board on so it flexed the wrong way).  I'm going to stick with a jigsaw and carbide tip (found in the tile section of the home center) for the rest of the project.

Answer (score 0):

we used a tub saw with an old blade.(NO WATER) cut out doors. use face mask and eye protection as it makes clouds of dust. draw size and cut free hand a the guide seemed to bind. cuts like butter!!  even a perfect bevel.